# Select multiple columns where one column ends in vba

Tags: excel, vba, automation

In excel, I have more data in column A than there is in any other column.  In all the other columns there are formulas that depend on the information in column A. I am writing a macro that will update the information in column A and then fill down the remaining columns to the point where column A ends.  I have written a piece of code that will select that portion of column B but I was wondering how I would modify this so that it would select columns B through AI? I am rather new to VBA so any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheet7.Range(Range("b1").End(xlDown), Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row,"B")).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have either a line of code for each column or make a loop.  I'll show you how to make your code into a loop.

## Code:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 to Range("AI1").Column
    Sheet7.Range(Sheet7.Cells(1,i).End(xlDown), Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row,i)).FillDown
    'The Code for Each Range Here!!
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If columns from "B" to "AI" have the same number of formulas, ending in the same row, the solution is quite easy: just replace "B" by "AI".

```
Sheet7.Range(Range("b1").End(xlDown), Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, "AI")).Select
```

Though I'd rewritten it in a bit more clear way:

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheet7
    .Range(Range("B1").End(xlDown), .Range("AI" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)).Select
End With
```

If columns from "B" to "AI" have different number of formulas or formulas are ending in different rows, please refer to answer, provided by jbarker2160.

Comment: Also, this solution only works if column "B" is the shortest.